# How do you structure python code to avoid long import statements?

Tags: python, import, structure

example directory structure and code:

```
root/
├─ main.py
├─ library/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ library_code.py
│  ├─ utilities/
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  ├─ utils_one.py
│  │  ├─ utils_two.py
```

```
# main.py

import library as lb
# lb.library_code is how you would access stuff
```

```
# library/__init__.py
import [library.]library_code
import [library.]utilities
```

```
# library.utilities.__init__.py
import [library.utilities.]utils_one
import [library.utilities.]utils_two
```

**how would you go about removing the text [inside these square brackets] on the import statements?**

of course, doing this kind of structure will cause this to not be possible:

```
# library/utilities/utils_one.py

import library.library_code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to just use a relative import. For example in utils_one.py you can do

```py
from . import utils_two
from .utils_two import function_one
```

You can also use `..` to go up a hierarchy just like with a file system

Answer (score 1):

You have it almost right. Use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports), e.g.:

```
# library.utilities.__init__.py
import .utils_one
import .utils_two
```